# Undo changes done by last database save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

When I press a button, jQuery uses ajax to delete an item, but it is possible for me to make another function that can "undo" the deletion that just took place?

**My delete controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void DeleteProject(int Id)
    {
        var Item = from a in db.Project
                   where a.ProjectId.Equals(Id)
                   select a;

        Project SelectedProject = Item.FirstOrDefault();
        ICollection<ProjectProfile> Profiles = SelectedProject.ProjectProfile;
        ICollection<Member> Members = SelectedProject.Member;

        db.Member.RemoveRange(Members);
        db.ProjectProfile.RemoveRange(Profiles);

        db.Project.Remove(SelectedProject);
        db.SaveChanges();

        RedirectToAction("Index", "Projects");
    }
```

Comment: Not unless your delete function is storing the "deleted" item in some other place after "deletion," like maybe a temp table that gets cleared out periodically.

Comment: Somebody tried to tackle this problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474279/Implementing-Undo-Redo-feature-for-DbContext-of-En

Answer (score 1):

There's a few way you could do this. Overall, it's a bit too broad to offer a clear-cut solution, but here's some ideas:

- Instead of deleting immediately, you could create a task that will run in a certain amount of time that will do the delete. Say, 10 seconds. For 10 seconds, you show an "undo" button that will cancel that task from running the `SaveChanges()`.
- You could cache the item you're deleting in a temporary table and restore it
- You could add an `IsDeleted` bit to your table and use that to signify that the record has been deleted which can be flipped at will to "un-delete".

Comment: I use the `IsDeleted` flag in most of my projects and never came up with the better idea, sadly.

Comment: it's definitely the simplest way, but could lead to bloat. other solutions would require other running processes or temporary that are harder to maintain perfectly.

Comment: I use DeleteDate which is DateTime? , so if it's null then it's not deleted, but if it has value then it's deleted + you get deletion time